# Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null And (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

Sending Email Verification not work without any reason and this error in photo what say. any solution?
It was working fine yesterday
[Terminal photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovEZc.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working, but when send many verification email the email (Domain) sender will be spam
so check from spam mail.
if its not work wait then try later.